# MySQL Query with variable wildcards

Tags: php, mysql, wildcard

If I execute my PHP code:

```
$serName = $_GET['username'];
// Code for sanitation here
// [...]
$sql = "SELECT NAME FROM PLAYERS WHERE NAME LIKE '%$serName%'";
```

I get division error, how do I use a variable in a query with wildcards on both sides?

Comment: You must sanitize your GET string before putting it at your query..

Comment: @Svetlio Yes I have sanatized it, I have just left it like that so people won't be confused my my functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

right query

```
SELECT NAME FROM PLAYERS WHERE NAME LIKE '%{$serName}%'
```

And you should use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Comment: Why cannot he use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) if he feels like it? (;

Comment: He certainly can :) I advised for prepared statements, not against PDO.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT NAME FROM PLAYERS WHERE NAME LIKE '%" .$serName. "%'";
```